# Expansión de variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17

Supongamos una función que debe recibir un número aleatorio de valores para sacarlos por pantalla separando dichos valores con un separador determinado.

La idea pasa por aprovechar las características de los nuevos estándares de C++ así que la solución debería provechar los *variadic templates*.

El primer intento resulta prometedor, la plantilla es capaz de imprimir una secuencia de números:

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
   (std::cout << ... << args) << '\n';
}


int main()
{
  print(1,2,3,4,5);
}
```

Ahora intento meter el separador y es cuando comienzan los problemas:

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
   (std::cout << ... << ',' << args) << '\n';
}
```

Detalles del error:

```
prog.cc:8:29: error: expression not permitted as operand of fold expression
   (std::cout << ... << ',' << args) << '\n';
                        ~~~~^~~~~~~
                        (      )
```

¿De qué manera se podría añadir el separador a la secuencia? La idea es obtener una secuencia tal que:

```
1,2,3,...,N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenía una respuesta a punto justo antes de la edición en la que dejas claro que la salida esperada es `1,2,3,...,N` y no `1,2,3,...,N,` como pensé al principio. Para el primer caso puede valer simplemente:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    ((std::cout << args << ','), ...);
}
```

Al no querer la coma después del último elemento la cosa se complica...

No se si será la mejor opción, pero se puede plantear de la siguiente forma modificando mi idea inicial:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
void print(Arg first, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << first;
    if (sizeof...(args) != 0)
        ((std::cout << ',' << args), ...);
}

int main()
{
    print(1);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print(1,2,3,4,5);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print("ab","c",3,4,"de");
    return 0;
}
```

Imprimimos el primer argumento y posteriormente nos valemos de un condicional para ver si hay algún argumento en `args` que desempaquetar o no.

Salida:

> 1
>   1,2,3,4,5
>   ab,c,3,4,de

[Prueba online en Ideone](http://ideone.com/t6yjpK)

Comment: Todos los puntos de vista son bienvenidos

Comment: Pues si, como casi siempre hay muchas formas de hacer lo mismo, unas mejores y otras peores. Me parece muy interesante tu pregunta, a ver si se suma mas gente con sus ideas.. :)

Answer (score 3):

A continuación expongo algunas otras formas de solucionar este problema aunque no son las únicas:

**Sobrecarga de la plantilla**

Por defecto se llamará a la versión *variadic* de la plantilla y solo se llamará a la versión no *variadic* cuando únicamente quede un elemento a imprimir.

La versión *variadic*, al llamarse siempre que haya 2 o más elementos puede asumir tranquilamente que debe insertar un separador después del primer elemento.

```
template<typename T>
void print(T item)
{
  std::cout << item;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(T item, Args... args)
{
  print(item);
  std::cout << ',';
  print(args...);
}
```

**Uso de lambdas (v1)**

Una lambda con estado es ideal para controlar la impresión del separador.

Al explotar los argumentos se realizaran numerosas llamadas a la lambda, que imprimirá un separador en cada una de las mismas salvo en la primera.

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    auto separador = [primero = true](auto param) mutable
    {
      if( !primero ) std::cout << ',';
      primero = false;
      return param;
    };

    ((std::cout << separador(args)), ...);
}
```

**Uso de lambdas (v2)**

Idéntica a la versión anterior, únicamente cambia la declaración de la variable booleana, que pasa a ser propiedad de la plantilla para evitar un warning en tiempo de compilación.

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    bool primero = true;
    auto separador = [&](auto param)
    {
      if( !primero ) std::cout << ',';
      primero = false;
      return param;
    };

    ((std::cout << separador(args)), ...);
}
```

**Uso de if constexpr**

Como el compilador ya sabe el número exacto de argumentos que recibe la función podemos hacer uso de `if constexpr` para que se realice una llamada recursiva únicamente mientras haya más de un elemento a imprimir. Este código podría entenderse como una mejora del primer ejemplo.

```
template <typename Item, typename... Args>
void print(Item item, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << item;
    if constexpr( sizeof...(args) > 0 )
    {
      std::cout << ',';
      print(args...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Estan muy bien, pienso que la ultima es la mas elegante, "en mi opinion" quizas porque parace mas facil de leer aunque eso dependera de para quien por eso digo en mi opinion. Saludos

Comment: Borrare este comentario, yo sobre la ultima la entendi pero pienso que la linea del `if` esta un poco pachucha, suguramente un error al escribir. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Las 4 soluciones compilan perfectamente. Las probé por si acaso antes de publicar la solución

Comment: ha pues quizas sea por el standard pero en c++14 sale lo siguiente ->  `function 'void print(Item, Args ...)':
9:8: error: expected '(' before 'constexpr'` Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel exacto, es una característica propia de c++17. Prueba a ejecutarlo en wandbox

Comment: umm es bueno saberlo, y tambien es verdad que la pregunta esta etiquetada con c++17. yo hice algunos cambios para probarla, y funcionaba por eso pense que era un error de typo.Saludos

Comment: Queria borrar los comentarios pero ahora me parecen utiles, quizas usted puede mencionar algo sobre esa caracteristica nueva para despistados como yo, es comentario si que lo borrare. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel esta noche que ahora estoy con el móvil

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que usted puede expandir la secuencia que recive el template hacia otra funcion a la cual le pasa los de args

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int print_test(int i)
{
    std::cout << ',' << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{

    using  expandir = int[]; 
    (void) expandir {0, ((void)print_test(args), 0)...};

    (std::cout << ... << args) << '\n'; // se deja para contrastar

}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    print(1,2,3,4,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Test <kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/0kCe9M)</kbd>

---

La explancion de los paquetes "Pack expansion" segun entiendo solo pueden ser expandidos en contextos de expancion de los mismo *"si quizas es un poco confuso siento no poder explicarme mejor"* por citar alguno inicializacion Braced o este en el que se basa el ejemplo inicializaciones de array.

info alguna info:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

pero en el se muestra como usted lo esta usando, no se si sera de utilidad para usted esa parte, pero en las definiciones de paquete "pack" "init" quizas lo ayude.

> Update:

Esto creo que funciona como usted quiere.

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    int chapuza = 0;
    const int n = sizeof...(args);

    using  expandir = int[]; 
    (void) expandir {0, ((void)print_test(args), chapuza++, chapuza == n ? std::cout << '\n' : std::cout << ','  << '\n', 0)...};

}
```

Test <kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/IRdpfp)</kbd>

Tras su update si es sin el salto de linea usar:

```
//..
(void) expandir {0, ((void)print_test(args), chapuza++, chapuza == n ? std::cout << '\n' : std::cout << ',', 0)...};
//..
```

cambiando `std::cout << ','  << '\n'` por `std::cout << ','`

---

Siguiendo con el enfoque anterior, se podria simplificar de la siguiente manera y prescindiendo de el `print_test`

```
    using  expandir = int[]; 
    (void) expandir {0, (chapuza++, chapuza == n ? std::cout << args << '\n' : 
                                                   std::cout << args<< ',', 0)...};
```

Test <kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/9TNW0y)</kbd>

---

Nota: quizas sea una *chapuza* y quizas exista una mejor forma, pero me dio curiosidad tras su comentario, y esto fue lo que salio, espero le ayude.

Comment: El uso de `expandir` es interesante, pero el problema que le veo a esta solución es que introduce un separador antes del primer elemento. La gracia es sacar una lista tal que `1,2,3,4,...,N` sin separadores ni al principio ni al final

Comment: @eferion cierto no me percate de eso cuando lo esta compilando, tiene razon. Saludos

Comment: @eferion le deje un update.Saludos

Comment: Pinta bastante mejor pero yo le quitaría el salto de línea que tienes tras la coma. Edité la pregunta para poner un ejemplo de cómo debería quedar la salida.

Comment: @eferion si justo lo esta publicando, pero quizas exista una manera mejor y mas simple, igual algo que quizas sea compatible con algun standard nuevo o para todos y yo no la conozco que esto es muy probable.Saludos

Comment: Ahora iba a publicar una respuesta con las alternativas que se me habían ocurrido a mí... a ver si con eso consigo picar a más gente para que haga su aportación

Comment: @eferion ya esta tardando, si no a mas gente yo quiero verla.Saludos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58195/discussion-between-eferion-and-angel-angel).